# Is finding a single vector in the null space as difficult as discovering the whole null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{k\times n}$ be a matrix of rank $k$, where $k \ll n$. One can use Gaussian eliminations to discover $\operatorname{null}(A)$ at the cost of $O(nk^2)$. My question is:

**Is the asymptotic lower bound for finding a single vector in $\operatorname{null}(A)$ also $O(nk^2)$?**

Comment: did you mean $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: @oxeimon No, I mean $A \in \mathbb R^{k\times n}$.

Comment: Certainly not. You can focus on a $k\times (k+1)$ submatrix and find a vector in $O(k^3)$ steps (assuming your bound is correct).

Comment: I changed $k<<n$ to $k\ll n$ (and did a bit of other copy-editing).  Standard usage.

Comment: What do you mean by "discover"? A basis contains (at least) $n-k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so to output one you need at least $O(n^2)$ operations.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I don't see how one can get the vector in $\mathbb R^n$ from the $k \times (k+1)$ submatrix. What about the other $n-k-1$ components?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you do not need a full-rank submatrix -- you are looking for vectors in its kernel, so lower rank gives you even more vectors in it.

Comment: @YuanGao You find $v\neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ in the kernel of the $k\times (k+1)$ submatrix and pad the vector with zeros in the other positions.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Similar question posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815803/how-to-extend-an-existing-orthogonal-set-of-vectors#comment1689691_815803 without any notice to either site.